# How to convert a tree to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, tree

I have this tree and i like to convert it to JSON to use it in [jquery option tree](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/).

```
NodeId, Title, Level
1, cars, 0
2, boats, 0
3, oldtimer, 1
4, trucks, 1
5, heavytrucks, 4
```

The tree should look like this:

```
boats
cars
- oldtimer
- trucks
-- heavytrucks
```

each item has a id.

How can i convert this to JSON?

This example will be given in jquery option tree:

```
var option_tree = {
    "Option 1": {
        "Suboption": 200
    },
    "Option 2": {
        "Suboption 2": {
            "Subsub 1": 201,
            "Subsub 2": 202
        },
        "Suboption 3": {
            "Subsub 3": 203,
            "Subsub 4": 204,
            "Subsub 5": 205
        }
    }
};
```

But Option 1 don't have an id, it has only child elements.

Comment: The option tree is attached to a text box. So the leaf value is inserted in the text box e.g. In the example when `Option 1` > ` Suboption` will be selected, the text box will have value `200`. In your tree (cars, boats...) the the leaf values are missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to make into json where is the data coming from that you want to convert to json ?

Comment: What do you want to convert to JSON?  Show us your current "tree".

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code will convert your input into a tree

```
var lines = 
   ('1, cars, 0\n' +
    '2, boats, 0\n' +
    '3, oldtimer, 1\n' +
    '4, trucks, 1\n' +
    '5, heavytrucks, 4').split('\n');

var tree = [];
var lookup = {}; // temporary variable

for (var i in lines) {
    var items = lines[i].split(', ');

    var obj = { id: items[0], parent_id: items[2], name: items[1], children: [] };
    lookup[obj.id] = obj;

    if (lookup[obj.parent_id]) {
        lookup[obj.parent_id].children.push(obj);
    } else {
        tree.push(obj);
    }
}

console.log(tree); // will display your tree
```

Then you can traverse your tree and modify it how you want it to look.

For example, this will print it

```
function walk(root, depth) {
    var s = ""; for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++) s += '-';
    console.log(s + ' ' + root.name);
    for (var child in root.children) {
        walk(root.children[child], depth+1);
    }
}

for (var child in tree)
    walk(tree[child], 1);
```

like this

```
- cars
-- oldtimer
-- trucks
--- heavytrucks
- boats
```

You can similarly convert it to whatever you want.

```
function walk2(root, parent) {
    if (root.children.length == 0) {
        parent[root.name] = root.id;
    } else {
        parent[root.name] = {}
        for (var child in root.children) {
            walk2(root.children[child], parent[root.name]);
        }
    }
}

var tree2 = {};

for (var child in tree)
    walk2(tree[child], tree2);

console.log(tree2); // <- is this what you wanted?
```

Comment: Nicely done mak. Note though: Your solution does not allow for input that is is not sorted. i.e. You cannot have '0, things, -1' as the last line in the input.